# Eclipse PDT code assist not recognizing object assignments to variables

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

For some reason, Eclipse's code assist stopped working for variables that are assigned objects.

For instance

```
// This returns a Model_Item object
$item = Model_Item::factory($id);

// Or this
$item = new Model_Item();
```

Now if you try to access the autocomplete

```
// Says there are no default proposals
$acct = $item->{ctrl+space}
```

However, if you do

```
// This works as expected
Model_Item::factory($id)->{ctrl+space}
```

Also, when I hover over $item, it doesn't tell me that it is a Model_Item.

Has anyone come across this before and figured out how to get it to work?

EDIT:

Looks like it's a bug.  I can get it to work if I do this:

```
$item = new Foo();
// No work here
$acct = $item->bar;
// But now it will work
$item->baz();
```

Not sure why this is this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more than likely a bug.  You should go to [Eclipse's bug tracker](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/) and first search to see if this bug has already been reported.  If this bug has not been reported, then you should report it yourself if you wish to see it fixed.  I did a quick search to see if I could find the bug, however nothing appeared to match the description, so you should probably go ahead and report the bug.